# Unable to install a package from the postinst of another package

Tags: 14.04, package-management, dpkg, packaging

I have Ubuntu 14.04.

I have 2 deb packages, `deb1` and `deb2`

I'm trying to install `deb2` in the postinst of `deb1` using `dpkg -i deb2` but I get this error:

```
dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process
```

To get around that, in my postinst I added this instruction to remove the lock:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

But then `deb1` installation failed:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
unable to install updated status of `deb1': 
No such file or directory`
```

However, when I don't try to install `deb2` from `deb1` the installation of `deb1` succeeds.

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: The lock exists for a reason.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Maybe there's a better way to do what you want.

Comment: The better way would be a good answer :) I have to admit I'm happy dpkg errored out on that. A postinst script deleting the lock file would be what I'd call malicious software!

Comment: People seem to have voted to close this as off topic because it uses the word "Debian" to mean "Debian package". They aren't usually called that. But the question is not off topic. However, it's almost certainly a dupe...